# Changing Quartile range

Tags: python, quartile

i have some data

```
a = pd.DataFrame([1,22,34,55,66,75,2,7,8,9,99,70,45,56,22,12,5,9,3,5,89,67,42,21])
```

when i use the describe function i get these below results:

```
a.describe()
Out[6]: 
               0
count  24.000000
mean   34.333333
std    30.786314
min     1.000000
25%     7.750000
50%    22.000000
75%    58.500000
max    99.000000
```

i get results showing the data in 0 to 25% , 25% to 50% and 50% to 75%.
i want to get results such that it shows results in 10%, 20% 30%... so on. Please let me know how to get these results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Numpy [`quantile`](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.quantile.html) by giving parameter `q` at required percentages like:

```
np.quantile(a,q=np.linspace(0.1,1,num=10))
array([ 3.6,  6.2,  8.9, 13.8, 22. , 40.4, 55.1, 66.4, 73.5, 99. ])
```

The quantile range is 10% to 100%:

```
np.linspace(0.1,1,num=10)
array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1. ])
```

---

Or using Numpy [`percentile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html):

```
np.percentile(a,q=np.linspace(10,100,num=10))
array([ 3.6,  6.2,  8.9, 13.8, 22. , 40.4, 55.1, 66.4, 73.5, 99. ])
```

The percentile range is 10% to 100%:

```
np.linspace(10,100,num=10)
array([ 10.,  20.,  30.,  40.,  50.,  60.,  70.,  80.,  90., 100.])
```

Comment: np.percentile worked for me. but i am getting this error for quantile. module 'numpy' has no attribute 'quantile'. my numpy version is 1.14.0

Comment: @aim The `quantile` function is added in `numpy=1.15.0` version. Update and check it will work.

Comment: @aim Please [`upvote and accept`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if the solutions provided your required result.